# error not reported when taking input of deleted resource(soft deletion) in laravel 5 php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a Model "Topics".

Say, I have soft deleted a resource with id=1 in topics.

I have another model "Posts" which has an attribute "topics_id".

Now,I tried to insert a resource in posts table with "topic_id"=1,it is getting inserted into the table.But, I want that to report an exception or error.I know this can be implemented in a controller just by checking it with "find" method.Is there any code that can be used in Model so that it doesn't get inserted.

Comment: Are your tables connected through foreign keys? Create constraints and then error will be raised automatically.

Comment: Yes .. I've did that.This is working fine for deletion but not working for soft deletion

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use model events?

See the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events

So on your `Post` model you could do the following which would trigger when creating a `Post`:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($post) {

        // check foreign key validaty
        // throw error if it doesn't exist

    });
}
```